# Start/Stop windows services remotely via bat file or cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-services

is there any solution how to stop/start services (eg. spooler) via cmd or bat file.

I tried solutions from google but no one successful.

**Solution 1:**

```
PsExec \\192.168.1.175 -u username -p password -h stop spooler
```

with the "**Solution 1**" I got this error.

[image]

**Solution 2**

```
sc \\192.168.1.175 stop spooler
```

with the "**Solution 2**" I got this error.

[image]

Comment: Type `sc /?` for help.

Comment: This seems like more of a [SuperUser] kind of problem. You apparently don't have access to the remote machine. It's likely they are locked-down from being remotely managed or you simply don't have the creds for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

**OPTION 1:** I got the solution from this URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction#how-to-disable-uac-remote-restrictions

**OPTION 2**

net use \192.168.1.175\admin$ **password** /user:**username**

and executing this command with CMD

```
sc \\192.168.1.175 stop spooler
```